# What is the pythonic way to bubble up error conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I have been working on a Python project that has grown somewhat large, and has several layers of functions.  Due to some boneheaded early decisions I'm finding that I have to go a fix a lot of crashers because the lower level functions are returning a type I did not expect in the higher level functions (usually None).

Before I go through and clean this up, I got to wondering what is the most pythonic way of indicating error conditions and handling them in higher functions?

What I have been doing for the most part is if a function can not complete and return its expected result, I'll return None.  This gets a little gross, as you end up having to always check for None in all the functions that call it.

```
def lowLevel():
    ## some error occurred
    return None

    ## processing was good, return normal result string
    return resultString

def highLevel():
    resultFromLow = lowLevel()
    if not resultFromLow:
        return None

    ## some processing error occurred
    return None

    ## processing was good, return normal result string
    return resultString
```

I guess another solution might be to throw exceptions.  With that you still get a lot of code in the calling functions to handle the exception.

Nothing seems super elegant. What do other people use?  In obj-c a common pattern is to return an error parameter by reference, and then the caller checks that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to do about the fact this processing can't be completed. If these are really exceptions to the ordinary control flow, and you need to clean up, bail out, email people etc. then exceptions are what you want to throw. In this case the handling code is just necessary work, and is basically unavoidable, although you can rethrow up the stack and handle the errors in one place to keep it tidier.

If these errors can be tolerated, then one elegant solution is to use the [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) pattern. Rather than returning None, you return an object that mimics the interface of the real object that would normally be returned, but just doesn't do anything. This allows all code downstream of the failure to continue to operate, oblivious to the fact there was a failure. The main downside of this pattern is that it can make it hard to spot real errors, since your code will not crash, but may not produce anything useful at the end of its run.

A common example of the Null Object pattern in Python is returning an empty list or dict when you're lower level function has come up empty. Any subsequent function using this returned value and iterating through elements will just fall through silently, without the need for error checking. Of course, if you *require* the list to have at least one element for some reason, then this won't work, and you're back to handling an exceptional situation again.

Answer (score 4):

On the bright side, you have discovered exactly the problem with using a return value to indicate an error condition.

`Exception`s are the pythonic way to deal with problems.  The question you have to answer (and I suspect you already did) is:  Is there a useful default that can be returned by `low_level` functions?  If so, take it and run with it; otherwise, raise an exception (`ValueError', 'TypeError' or even a custom error).

Then, further up the call stack, *where you know how to deal with the problem*, catch the exception and deal with it.  You don't have to catch exceptions immediately -- if `high_level` calls `mid-level` calls `low_level`, it's okay to not have any `try/except` in `mid_level` and let `high_level` deal with it.  It may be that all you can do is have a `try/except` at the top of your program to catch and log all uncaught and undealt-with errors, and that can be okay.

Answer (score 3):

This is not necessarily *Pytonic* as such but experience has taught me to let exceptions "lie where they lie".

That is to say; Don't unnecessarily hide them or re-raise a different exception.

It's sometimes good practice to let the callee fail rather than trying to capture and hide all kinds of error conditions.

Obviously this topic is and can be a little subjective; but if you don't hide or raise a different exception, then it's much easier to debug your code and much easier for the callee of your functions or api to understand what went wrong.

*Note:* This answer is not complete -- See comments. Some or all of the answers presented in this Q&A should probably be combined in a nice way presneting the various problems and solutions in a clear and concise manner.

Comment: This misses the main purpose of *re-raising* exceptions - to present a unified exception API to the caller. For example, if I implement a web service submission in my code using HTTP POST, that submit operation could raise `urllib2.HTTPError` (server-side processing error), `urllib2.URLError` (wrong URL, endpoint down), `ValueError` (URL not parseable, or missing), `httplibInvalidURL` (URL parseable, but not valid), and in rare cases, other errors. If I don't deal with these, then my caller has to. Ugly! Instead I catch them all, raise a ConnectionError, and add a context string as necessary.

Comment: As far as letting them just fail goes - that only works if you can tolerate run time errors ending your process. This can be handy in testing, but for most production software, that isn't what you want.

Comment: These are very good points and quite valid as well. Obviously a suitable acceptable answer needs someone to spend more than 2mins answering :) I feel like this should have been answered and even asked before though :/

Comment: @ire_and_curses: James said "Don't **unneccessarily** hide them or ..."  Sure there are good reasons to change the original exception, but there are also plenty of bad ones to do so.  Also, "letting them fail" does not mean letting the whole program die; if `low_level` raises an exception then it has failed.  You can still catch it and deal with it further up the call stack.

Comment: @EthanFurman Thank you for backing my position. I will try to revise this answer to be more clear on all points. Perhaps then it might get a bit more of an up-vote :) Problem with this topic is there is no _one_ solution, it's highly dependent on what you're doing. In general though you should not hide exceptions or raise new/different ones unless you have a very good reason. You should let exceptions fall where they lie (*in the callee*) and catch them in your caller as required (*optional*).

Comment: @Ethan Furman - I don't think we disagree. The original answer is vague, and left a lot of room for ambiguity, and implied to me a stronger position than was warranted. The OP is not experienced, and could easily read too much into these statements. That's why I've pointed out these issues.

Comment: @ire_and_curses: Fair enough, although I think your answer is covering more the library stand-point, while James' the application's.